# Missing GPS Tools button

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Following the guidance at, 
http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/plugins_gps.html
I checked my Plugins Manager and verified that GPS Tools is enabled. However, unlike what the reference site indicated, I only have one button on my tool bar--the one for "Create New GPX Layer"; not the one for "GPS Tools", which is used for loading GPS data from a GPS unit.

Any idea why I'm missing that button? Or how I should load data from my GPS unit? (I'm using QGIS 1.8.0 and Windows 7.)

Thanks
TVZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select `View -> Toolbars` from the Menu and check the `Vector` entry.

The icon looks identical to "Create new GPX Layer".

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much for your patience. My GPS Tools button was hidden and in a different area of the tool bar; but I found it when I clicked on the double-arrow to expand the vector tools. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

According to your question. Please check the screenshot in this I have highlighted few things such as GPS tools button ,Download GPS data etc.

GPS tools found under (Vector--GPS--GPS tools) . Please check this and let us know if you gave any question

If you are new to QGIS then please check following tutorials

[Video Tutorial 1](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/qgis-video-tutorials/)  by @underdark

[Tutorial 2](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com) by Ujaval Gandhi

thanks

[image: QGIS_GPS_tool]

Comment: I'm sorry guys, maybe I'm missing something obvious- 

The User Guide link says that the plugin creates two tool similar buttons--one for "Create New GPX Layer"; and one for "GPS Tools". Your (Sunil’s) screenshot shows only one such button. However, in your case it’s apparently the GPS Tools button. When I hover over mine, it says “Create New GPX layer”. When I click it, it comes up w/ a “Save new GPX file as” screen. I can’t find anything there relating to GPS tools or the screenshot you provided. Do you have any idea why this might be, or what I might do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to locate the GPS tools in QGIS 3.28.11 (Firenze) and its hidden under Layers' Menu > Data source Manager; Click on Data Source manager as shown in the image below:-
[image]
GPS tools screenshot located under Layer's Menu/Data source Manager